# Como truncar datos

Tags: javascript, html, python, jquery

me encuentro atascado con realizar una función que trunque el plazo de un contrato con el tipo de transacción que se escoge, me dieron una imagen de referencia pero no logro llevarla a lo que me piden y la adjuntare por si alguien logra entender como se desarrolla lo que me estan pidiendo. Es un archivo html lo que estoy modificando y debo ocupar un jquery para truncar estos dos datos y donde estoy haciendo todo esto es python y tambien adjuntare el codigo del html para que lo revisen estimad@s, gracias por su tiempo.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h4>Creaci&oacute;n Cabecera O.A. - Informaci&oacute;n Cliente</h4>
<p>Paso {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} de {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div id="fields">
{{ wizard.management_form }}

{% for hidden in wizard.form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}

<table>
{% for field in wizard.form.visible_fields %}
    <tr><td style="min-width: 230px; height: 30px;" valign=top><b>{% if field.label == 'Cliente' %}<label for="id_step_1-cliente">{{ field.label }} : </label>{% else %}{{ field.label }} : {% endif %}</b></td><td valign=top>{{ field }}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <br><font color="red">&middot; {{ error }}</font>
    {% endfor %}
    </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
<br>

{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "Primer Paso" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Paso Previo" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input class="bloquear_cliente_oa" type="button" value="{% trans "Siguiente" %}" onclick="Siguiente();"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var n_contratos = 0;

async function Siguiente(){
    if(n_contratos == 0){
        $("#id_step_1-leasing").removeAttr("disabled");
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    } else {
        if(await confirmPopUp("El cliente ya tiene "+n_contratos+" Contrato(s), desea Continuar ?")){
            $("#id_step_1-leasing").removeAttr("disabled");
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        }
    }
}

function Contratos(){
    $.post( "/SAIApp/contratosCliente/", { customer_id: $("#id_step_1-cliente").val(), csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()}, function(data){})
    .done( function(data) {
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        n_contratos = obj.length;
        if(n_contratos == 0){
            $("label[for='id_step_1-cliente']").html("Cliente:");
        } else {
            info = "<div id='con_info' class='tbox-container'><div id='info' class='tbox'><table class='tbox-table'>";
            info+= "<tr><td><b>Contratos</b></td><td><b>:</b></td><td>"+n_contratos+"</td></tr>";
            /*for(i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                info+= "<tr><td><b>Contratos "+obj[i].pk+"</b></td><td><b>:</b></td><td>"+n_contratos+"</td></tr>";
            }*/
            info+= "</table></div></div>";
            $("label[for='id_step_1-cliente']").html("<table><tr><td>Cliente:&nbsp;</td><td><div onmouseover='OnMouseOver();' onmouseout='OnMouseOut();' onclick='OnClick();'><img src='{% static "SAIApp/images/search.png" %}'></div>"+info+"</td></tr></table>");
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        n_contratos = 0;
        $("label[for='id_step_1-cliente']").html("Cliente:");
    });
}

function Leasing(){
    if($("#id_step_1-leasing").prop("checked")) {
        $("#fields table tr").each(function(index) {
            $row = $(this);
            if($row.html().indexOf("id_step_1-leasing_cliente") >= 0){
                $row.show();
            } else if($row.html().indexOf("id_step_1-leasing_direccion") >= 0){
                $row.show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#fields table tr").each(function(index) {
            $row = $(this);
            if($row.html().indexOf("id_step_1-leasing_cliente") >= 0){
                $row.hide();
            } else if($row.html().indexOf("id_step_1-leasing_direccion") >= 0){
                $row.hide();
            }
        });

        $('#id_step_1-leasing_cliente').val(null).trigger('change');
        $('#id_step_1-leasing_direccion').val(null).trigger('change');
    }
}

function OnMouseOver(){
    document.getElementById("con_info").style.top = String(-16-$("#info").height())+"px";
    document.getElementById("con_info").style.left = String(-$("#info").width())+"px";
    document.getElementById("info").style.display = "block";
}

function OnMouseOut(){
    document.getElementById("info").style.display = "none";
}

function OnClick(){
    var url = "/SAIApp/generacionContratos/?csrfmiddlewaretoken="+$("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()+"&numero=&cliente="+$("#id_step_1-cliente").val()+"&tipo_transaccion=&submit=BUSCAR&tab=tab1";
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}

function CheckLeasing(){
    if($("#id_step_1-tipo_transaccion option:selected").text().indexOf("1324 - ") >= 0){
        $("#id_step_1-leasing").prop( "checked", true );
    } else {
        $("#id_step_1-leasing").prop( "checked", false );
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    Contratos();
    CheckLeasing();
    Leasing();
    $("#id_step_1-leasing").attr('disabled','disabled');
    clientePreferencial('#id_step_1-cliente');
    clienteBloqueadoContado('#id_step_1-cliente');
    //EVALUACION CLIENTE
    evaluacionCliente('#id_step_1-cliente');

    //EVALUACION DIRECCION
    evaluacionDireccion('#id_step_1-cliente','#id_step_1-direccionfacturacion');
});

$("#id_step_1-cliente").change(function() {
    $('#id_step_1-direccionfacturacion').val(null).trigger('change');
    Contratos();
    clientePreferencial($(this).val());
    clienteBloqueadoContado($(this).val());
    //EVALUACION CLIENTE
    evaluacionCliente('#id_step_1-cliente');
});

$("#id_step_1-leasing_cliente").change(function() {
    $('#id_step_1-leasing_direccion').val(null).trigger('change');
});

$("#id_step_1-leasing").change(function() {
    Leasing();
});

$("#id_step_1-tipo_transaccion").change(function() {
    CheckLeasing();
    Leasing();
});

$("#id_step_1-direccionfacturacion").change(function() {
    direccionBloqueadoContado($('#id_step_1-cliente').val(), $('#id_step_1-direccionfacturacion').val());

    //EVALUACION DIRECCION
    evaluacionDireccion('#id_step_1-cliente','#id_step_1-direccionfacturacion');
});

$("#id_step_1-implementacion").change(function() {
    if($("#id_step_1-implementacion").prop("checked")) {
        alert('Solo seleccione esta opcion, si el contrato sera implementado en multiples OAs');
    }
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Ejemplo de los datos que se tienen que truncar o bien limitar]

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, tu pregunta no se acomoda al formato del sitio, por favor, refíerete a lo que quisieras obtener como resultado y pasa la imagen a código en un formato legible o copiable. Puedes referenciarte del siguiente [enlance](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @ʀᴏᴅʀɪɢᴏʀ. gracias por tu respuesta y en cuanto a lo que pides, el codigo de la imagen ya se encuentra dentro del código de arriba pero la adjunte ya que me dijeron que me guiara de esas funciones en especifico y  aqui va algo mas especifico a lo que pido. Hay que hacer que el campo plazo contrato se trunque dependiendo del tipo de transacción utilizado

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con truncar? ¿De qué depende el tipo de transacción y cómo cambia? ¿Qué valores puede tener?

Comment: @MarceloZárate me refiero a que el dato plazo contrato despliegue el listado de opciones según el tipo de transacción seleccionado, voy adjuntar una imagen con los datos para explicarme mejor

Comment: @MarceloZárate estimado agregue una foto mas clara de los datos que tengo que trabajar y como muestra la imagen necesito que si se escoge el arriendo temporal solo muestre los meses 1 a 5

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el html generado? Como no muestras el código de django no hay forma de saber cómo se llaman las etiquetas generadas por el form wizard. Principalmente el html entre `<form>` y `</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu necesitas, a mi parecer y segun he leido, es una relación entre el campo "Tipo de transacción" y el campo "Plazo Contrato", de tal manera que cuando marques en el primero, busques para listas cuales son los "meses" que le corresponde a ese dato marcado (Base de datos -> busqueda ID "Tipo de transacción" -> subconsulta a la tabla donde contengas los valores de los meses u donde queráis tener la relación, retraes una lista con los datos, y cargas el segundo campo "Plazo Contrato").

Me faltan datos para decirte algo mejor.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta estimado y estas en lo correcto es algo como lo que mencionas lo que tengo que lograr pero no se como llevarlo a jQuery, básicamente seria una restricción según el tipo de transacción

Comment: Pero tienes una base de datos, no? Lanzas la peticion desde front a traves de Jquery con un método AJAX, en la variable Data mete algo que te identifique el primer combobox element (normalmente llevara asociado un ID) buscalo y carga un listado con los meses, no se si lo tienes en la Base de Datos, o donde, luego regresa la respuesta con el listado y en el metodo .sucess de AJAX recarga el segundo combobox (meses) con el listado que traes desde back.

Comment: Estimado tengo muy poca experiencia trabajando con temas de JQuery, python y cosas como Django y Ajax por lo que comprendo lo que me dices pero no logro llevarlo a código  no se si me puedes ayudar con un ejemplo simple para poder guiarme y las id de los datos serian id_step_1-tipo_transaccion y id_step_1-plazo_contrato. Además que no creo estar usando AJax si esta implementado Django